# Line Sync when there is supposed to be no ADSL codes on the line?

Tags: ppp, hardware

I have a client who had ADSL (1500/256), and in an attempt to get her a faster connection, she tried to churn to a different provider.

Long story short, the other provider will not supply adsl because the line quality is too poor (or) she is too far from the exchange.

When she tried to reinstate the connection with the previous provider (it had to be cancelled and codes removed for the new provider to try), they are now saying the same thing.

So apparently there is no ADSL codes on the line, but when I was onsite the other evening I noticed that the modem still had line sync.
How is this possible?

Does that mean she probably could get ADSL back if "a" provider would activate an account for the modem to authenticate to?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESyej.png

Comment: This is more of a discussion than network engineering question.  This is the classic response from an ISP that doesn't want to sell legacy DSL anymore. *cough*AT&T*cough* The line is clearly functional, as it _is_ currently functioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gonna take a guess here that your in Australia.

The cutoff for getting a new ADSL connection from Telstra or any Telstra reseller is 56dB of attenuation at 300khz based on the calculated loss from the cabling records.

Your modem is reporting 63dB attenuation so chances are the calculated loss is higher than 56dB.

When you got ADSL in the first place the loss check must have been bypassed somehow or your cabling records were wrong and calculated at less than 56dB of loss.

Whatever the reason your cabling records now say you cant get ADSL and you have no existing ADSL service on the line.

Its not a technical limitation is a procedural/policy limitation.

You will probably need to go through a manger/escaltion/shouting match with management of your original provider to get the ADSL reinstated.

Comment: thanks for that.  I thought it'd be a policy or a minimum service standards issue that made them refuse to add a service.

Answer (score 2):

> So apparently there is no ADSL codes on the line, but when I was
>   onsite the other evening I noticed that the modem still had line sync.
>   How is this possible?

"Codes" is the term used for whether a DSL wholesale providers/ISP's provisioning database acknowledges there is an active service on the line.

Line sync only relies on the customers telephone line being jumpered (cabled) to the DSLAM within the exchange/central office.

Often if port availability is not an issue, the jumpering will be left in tact, when the service is cancelled ("codes" are removed).

Comment: and thank you for explaining why there's still be line sync, when there is no "codes" on the service.  It helps me understand that it's not a ports issue, but more of a line quality issue as the reason they knocked her back.

Comment: can I accept both responses as answers and split points/rep?